# HTML Tables (side-by-side) not fitting in jumbotron

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to place a list of products in individual tables and then place them side by side for display.

Originally, the tables stack on top of one another like so and fit within the jumbotron design:

http://i.snag.gy/zgBtG.jpg

I want them stacked side by side like so:

http://i.snag.gy/g0huA.jpg

However, when I do this, things get a little messed up and the tables do not stay within the jumbotron design.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: central;
  padding: 5px;
}
.products {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<?php // Run a select query to get my latest 6 items // Connect to the MySQL database include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; $dynamicList="" ; $sql=m ysql_query( "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 12"); $productCount=m ysql_num_rows($sql);
// count the output amount if ($productCount>0) { while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { $id = $row["id"]; $product_name = $row["product_name"]; $price = $row["price"]; $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"])); $dynamicList .= '
<table class="products" width="220px" border="1"
cellpadding="6">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">
          <img width="200px" height="250px" style="border: #CCCCCC 1px solid;" src="http://rapidcodes.co.uk/inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="$dynamicTitle">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><strong>' . $product_name . '</strong></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>£' . $price . '</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>'; } } else { $dynamicList = "We have no products listed in our store yet"; } mysql_close(); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Rapid Codes - Get it now!</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <?php include_once( "template_header.php");?>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <p>Newest Additions</p>
      <?php echo $dynamicList; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p>P1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p>P2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p>P3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p>P4</p>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
    </div>
    <?php include_once( "template_footer.php");?>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Apologies for the messy code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cannot get my head around this one.

Comment: instead of doing `.products { float: left; }`, try `.products { display: inline-block; }`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Why I didn't try that I don't know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you're welcome, i posted it as an answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of doing `.products { float: left; }`, try `.products { display: inline-block; }`

floating elements takes them out of the normal DOM structure (you can imagine these elements as if they are on a different layer above the normal DOM). In your second image, you can see that the jumbotron is smaller because it doesnt recognize that the table elements are inside of it (since they are "floated" above the jumbotron now) so it defaults to its normal size when it contains no contents.

by using `display: inline-block`, the elements keep their block space but do not take up the whole horizontal space they normally would, but only the space they need, which allows for other elements to be placed next to them.